# No appropriate python interpreter found. Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-cli, cassandra-2.1

I am a java developer and am very new to Linux and Cassandra. I am using CentOS6. I am trying to install **Cassandra3.4** in the Linux machine. I have followed the steps mentioned in [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cassandra/cassandra_installation.htm).

Looks like the Linux machine already has Python installed. When I tried `python -V`
in my putty connected to the Linux machine, I got the following output in my putty. `Python 2.6.6`
. I am assuming python is installed.FYKI, I have no clue how python works.

After I completed the installation process, I ran the cassandra service with the following command. `/opt/cassandra/bin/cassandra -f -R &`. It was all good.

Now, here comes the problem. When I run `./cqlsh` I get the following error.

> No appropriate python interpreter found.

I did my research and tried out a couple of options, but nothing was fruitful so far.

1. [Try 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24871787/cqlsh-under-cygwin-fails-without-an-error-message)
2. [Try 2](http://grokbase.com/t/cassandra/user/128ytz5egj/cassandra-cqlsh)
3. [Try 3](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cassandra-user/201311.mbox/%3COF58952E3E.D3EEC125-ONC1257C1B.004DBE91-C1257C1B.004EEF16@urssaf.fr%3E)
4. [Try 4](https://www.mail-archive.com/user@cassandra.apache.org/msg33136.html)
5. [Try 5](http://qnalist.com/questions/4605050/running-cqlsh-throws-no-appropriate-python-interpreter-found)

None of the above links worked for me. Or probably I am not smart enough to  understand. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Which Cassandra version you are using ?

Comment: I am using  Cassandra3.4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you should try to update your Python to 2.7 version , because Cassandra 3.x requires Python 2.7

You can refer:

```
[http://thecpaneladmin.com/how-to-upgrade-python-on-centos/][1]
```

Assuming you have not changed any python configuration while installation, 
it should work.
You can try and let us know.

Comment: Will try that and get back to you.

Comment: Firtsly, thanks for your answer. I followed the steps mentioned in the site you mentioned. I am stuck in this step: './configure –prefix=/usr/local' . I am getting the following error.
_configure: error: invalid variable name: `prefix'_
Any clue?

Comment: @Andy 

You are copypasting the command from the site , try typing it 

its --prefix ( two hyphens - - )

Answer (score 3):

**Install your won version of python from source:**

```
wget http://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.6/Python-2.7.6.tgz

tar -xvzf Python-2.7.6.tgz

cd Python-2.7.6

./configure --prefix=/usr/local

make

make install
```

Now any scripts that require the alternate version should have the following shebang:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7
```

**using pip:**

/usr/local/bin/pip2.7

[source](http://thecpaneladmin.com/how-to-upgrade-python-on-centos/)